# jQuery Shapeshift-Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am trying to trigger an event of the plugin "jQuery Shapeshift", but not getting the way how it works. Does anyone know the error in my code? Is it the wrong event (pageinit), where should I put the function else? Whats my issue .. please help :/

Btw. my grid is initialized properly and functionality is running (shapeshifted ..), but event triggering does not work.

Events: https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift/wiki/2.0-api-documentation

My try:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#entry", function( event ) {

    initializeGrid();

    <!-- onMove -->
    var $containers = $(".ss-container");
    $containers.on("ss-rearranged", function(e, selected) {
        alert('hi');
    });
    <!-- end onMove -->

}); <!-- end event page init -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **`ss-rearranged`** binding to look like this:

```
$(document).on("ss-rearranged", ".ss-container" ,function(e, selected) {
    alert('hi');
});
```

and move it out of a **`pageinit`** event.